# What is the best way to get image from vertex group?

Tags: uv, blender-internal-render-engine, vertex-groups

I have a *UV unwrapped* plane and some faces assigned in Vertex Group. What is the best way to get an image from this data? Maybe a  bLack and white image, it would best  if it could be scripted in the `bpy`
[image]

Comment: Not entirely sure if I understand you correctly. Do you mean exporting the UV layout into an image?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? what will this data be used for?

Comment: you can assign vertex colors to the vertex group and then bake it as a texture

Comment: I'm too lazy to write it all out but you can see the process of doing it manually here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsilkGVy_dQ The only issue in automating it would be getting the x and y size of the image required if you want to make it as wide in pixels as it's wide in polygons. But that shouldn't be an issue if the plane is automatically generated too

Comment: Check out bpy.ops.uv.export_layout.

Comment: Btw: If you need black and white output for export_layout set opacity to 1. Afterwards you could use ImageMagick: `convert exported.png -channel alpha -threshold 50% -white-threshold 0 -alpha Off png:- | convert - -morphology Close:1 Diamond final.png`